# Error while porting odoo 9 module to odoo 10: Element '<xpath expr="//group[@name='sale_grp']">' cannot be located in parent view

Tags: python, module, report, odoo, port

Element '' cannot be located in parent view

Error context:
View `res.company.form.inherited`
[view_id: 908, xml_id: n/a, model: res.company, parent_id: 111]
None" while parsing `enter code here`file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Odoo%2010.0/server/odoo/addons/custom_reports/views/qteco_customization_view.xml:4, near

```
<record id="res_company_inherited" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">res.company.form.inherited</field>
            <field name="model">res.company</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_company_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <data><xpath expr="//field[@name='company_registry']" position="after">
                    <field name="bank"/>
                    <field name="iban"/>
                    <field name="bic"/>
                    <field name="kvk"/>
                    <field name="btw_nr"/>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="//group[@name='sale_grp']" position="replace">
                    <group name="sale_grp" string="Sale Terms and Conditions">
                        <field name="sale_note" nolabel="1" placeholder="Default terms &amp; conditions..."/>
                    </group>
                    <group name="covering_letter_grp" string="Covering Letter Note">
                        <field name="covering_ltr_note" nolabel="1"/>
                    </group>
                </xpath>
            </data></field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving is due to the xpath expression failing. Sorry to state the obvious. Take a look at the view you are inheriting from `base.view_company_form` and look for a group with the name of `sale_grp`, if you cant find it then you have to find the form it is in and inherit it or choose a different xpath entry point to place your `sale_grp` xml. If you see another named group you can just replace `sale_grp` in the expr and it should work assuming the fields are available in the model in Odoo 10.

Comment: You should also check the priority of the views, if you are modifying a field from an inherited view, make sure your view is rendered last by set high priority for it. The above error could occur if your view is rendered before the inherited view that contains the field you want to modify. Cheers.